# How to outputs windows FQDN (hostname) on AWS Cloudformation template outputs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

My template creates a windows stack. Template's useddata creates a machine object (say computer name) and windows instance in ASG creates successfully. I'm trying to output private IP Address and FQDN - Hostname in cfn outputs. Do you guys have any suggestions or any sample template which does the similar trick?

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work". Does it throw an error or output wrong value? How you are doing it?

Comment: questions have been updated. I had tried for IP address few months ago, it didnt work so i gave up. I dont remember the exact error anymore. Now Im wondering if Hostnames can be output if at all possible. If its not possible, I will have find an another way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating an autoscaling group, your CloudFormation object does not include the resulting server instance, thus you cannot interact with it.

If you create EC2 individual instances, the right way to get this data would be [Fn::GetAtt.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html)

In your case your output block should look like (given EC2 object called MyInstance):

```
"Outputs" : {
  "PrivateIp" : {
    "Description" : "MyInstance Private IP Address",
    "Value" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "MyInstance", "PrivateIp" ] }
  }
}
```

For FQDN you can use:

```
 { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "MyInstance", "PublicDnsName" ] }
```

Comment: gave you +1. my CFN template has ASG which was the requirement for me as we need to instance to recover itself once it fails.  So i started using the CLI to get my output.